# Deleting a post

Tags: support, comment, flagging, answers, deletion

Today I encountered a person writing his comment as an answer as because he only have 35 bounties.

So is there anyway by which you can delete such kind of answers OR any other user who is capable of commenting, just comment it on the appropriate place and then delete the answer.

Sometimes it takes lot of time to read such kind of answers and then finally come to know that they were just comments.

Kindly help!!!

Comment: May I introduce you to [flags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4328/8348)? (originally had wrong link.. oops.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer Sure Sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such answers, please use the "flag" button and mark it as "not an answer".  A moderator can then convert it to a comment or delete it as appropriate.